# Windows equivalent to Mac Time Machine?

Tags: backup, windows-server-2008

Is there a good product to have backup images of Windows like Time Machine?
In case it matters, I have Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise Server, with various development tools installed.

Comment: Or, indeed, XP/ Vista / Win7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symantec Ghost would be the best suitable software.

You can see more here:

http://www.symantec.com/norton/ghost

Comment: will Ghost work for making an image of Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise Server?

Comment: Absolutely: http://www.symantec.com/business/products/sysreq.jsp?pcid=pcat_infrastruct_op&pvid=865_1

Comment: another question, i'm assuming that Ghost will make some file, and then I will store that file in some external drive. If I need to install/recover using the image, do I make the new computer boot from that external drive, and the Ghost image will be bootable, then ALL of my programs will be installed, including the OS, absolutely ALL the files I had originally?

Comment: You will have to boot from something. That can be the external drive, an USB pen drive, a CDROM or even an ancient floppy. You just need something to boot and some way for what you booted to access the image you want to restore. (E.g. boot from a CD using DOS and the mscdex driver, then start ghost and restore to disk).

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 includes a fairly good Backup and Restore center, which can do full disk backups, and selective file restores, from an arbitrary drive (Though obviously, on the drive you're backing up from isn't a backup at all).

It's not as pretty as time machine, but it works well.

Answer (score 0):

With Windows Home Server, you get automated daily, weekly, and monthly aged backups. (Time Machine also does hourly.) It is intended to completely restore a system if necessary, even making easy-to-access copies of necessary drivers to do so.

One difference is that instead of buying just an external drive, it requires a whole server box, although they are intended to run headless, so it's not that much more expensive. The integration for "going back in time" for individual files is not there; you have to view the entire old backup and poke around.

But as a server box, it will backup everyone on the network (sorta like Time Capsule). It provides an expandable pool of storage -- just add a drive -- and storage redundancy, putting copies in more than one place if possible. It is also intended to be a central media/document server for multiple users.